# Integrating Celery to Flask application running in windows virtual environment

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have been creating a flask application to process GNSS data receive by the user. In the flask application data processing done in backend. Since GNSS data processing takes a long time currently user have to wait few minutes without closing the browser to get the result via email.

Therefore I decided to integrate Celery with Flask application.

Based on the available documentations I have installed RabbitMQ Server on local C: drive by downloading the **rabbitmq-server-3.7.3.exe** file.

In order to learn integration of Celery with Flask I followed [this video 2:15](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fg-JfZBetpM&list=PLXmMXHVSvS-DvYrjHcZOg7262I9sGBLFR) once I tried to restart rabbitmq-server with following command

> service rabbitmq-server restart

It gives me following error

***'service' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.***

After creating ***tasks.py file***

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://localhost//')
@app.task
def reverse(string):
    return string[::-1]
```

I ran following command

> celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info

Gives following error
***WindowsError: [Error 87] The parameter is incorrect***

My other question is how he has intergrated ubuntu console in windows 10 like in above video

Answer (score 0):

Use this link https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows-manual.html to register rabbitmq as a service in windows.

after that try using rabbitmq as amqp://localhost:5672 in celery